# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, syntax-error

I came across this error while doing an ajax request and after looking over if I simply can't find the problem. Here is the code below.

```
$('#post_submit').click(function() {

var poster_id = <?php echo $session_user_id; ?>;
//firebug syntax error shows the line below is the problem
var profile_user_id: <?php echo $user_id; ?>;
var post = $('#post').val();
$.post('ajax_submit_post.php', 
    {
        profile_user_id: profile_user_id,
        poster_id: poster_id,
        comment_type : comment_type,
        post: post      
    }, 
    function () {
        $('#status').append('<li class="hide">Posted</li>').hide(1000); 
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant to use the equals sign?

```
var profile_user_id = <?php echo $user_id; ?>;
```

instead of

```
var profile_user_id: <?php echo $user_id; ?>;
```

Comment: Yeah, I spotted it right when it notified me that you responded with an answer. I'll give you the check when it lets me.